# Declare C# Class That Implements a Generic Interface

Tags: c#, class, generics, interface, implements

Suppose I have an empty interface class IBaseInterface which is used only to "label" implementing classes as being interfaces themselves.

Is there any way to do something like this?

For example:

```
public class MyClass : T where T : IBaseInterface
{
}
```

Comment: How would the generic type work?

Comment: In .NET you better use attributes instead of empty interfaces if you just want to tag/mark a class for a specific behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't do that, since the compiler has to know which interface the class implements when you declare the class. You can have *generic parameters* **to** the interface, but the actual interface has to be specified.

Answer (score 2):

Not like that, there isn't. I would strongly recommend using a composition pattern to try and achieve whatever you're trying. As an alternative, you might find [DynamicProxy](http://www.castleproject.org/dynamicproxy/index.html) (or some other proxy solution) is what you're going for.

Answer (score 0):

The type you're declaring isn't even generic. Something like this:

```
class MyClass<T> : T where T : IBaseInterface
```

could work under some circumstances (for example, if C++ templates were used instead of .Net generics), but it's simply not valid C# code.

I'm not sure what are the “labels” used for, but an interface with a property

```
ClassType ClassType { get; }
```

where 
`ClassType` is an `enum` could work.